# Using a input variable as a numeric and string on a Shiny APP

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyapps, shiny-reactivity

So, i created a program to optimize my marketing budget.
As an input, the user need to set the total budget. I create this input variable as "cust_tot" in the Shiny UI code below:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Budget Optimizer"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      numericInput("custo_tot", "Valor total do Investimento:", value = 3243452, min = 0),
      actionButton("submit", "Otimizar")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("grafico_investimento_atual")
    )
  )
)
```

In order to get the data, i need to query, but the variable "custo_tot" (inputed by the user) is also going to be part of the query:

in my original code, it was something like that:

```
sql <- " query here " 
sql = gsub("custo_rest_min_aux", custo_rest_min_aux, sql)
sql = gsub("custo_rest_max_aux", custo_rest_max_aux, sql)
sql = gsub("month_rest", sQuote(month_rest), sql)
sql = gsub("custo_tot", input$custo_tot, sql)
  
tb <- bq_project_query(projectid, sql)
df = bq_table_download(tb) %>% data.frame()
```

But i know that i cant simply use input$custo_tot because it shows the following error message:

```
Error in input$custo_tot : 
  Can't access reactive value 'custo_tot' outside of reactive consumer.
ℹ Do you need to wrap inside reactive() or observe()?
```

how should i deal with this?

Comment: What does the server function look like? You posted the error but not the corresponding code where you call `input$custo_tot`.

Comment: Sorry, it was just an example. this code is inside the server function . The error i mentioned was when i tried to use  sql = gsub("custo_tot", input$custo_tot, sql). I just wanna be able to use this input variable as a string to make a query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error specifies, you cannot access the `input` list unless you are inside a reactive consumer:

```r
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  sql <- reactive({
    sql <- " query here " 
    sql = gsub("custo_rest_min_aux", custo_rest_min_aux, sql)
    sql = gsub("custo_rest_max_aux", custo_rest_max_aux, sql)
    sql = gsub("month_rest", sQuote(month_rest), sql)
    sql = gsub("custo_tot", input$custo_tot, sql)
    sql
  })
  
}
```

This will make it a reactive so any time the inputs are updated this reactive will lazily update. Remember to use this reactive you need to call it like: `sql()`.

Comment: I need to use the query to load dataset for further usage. Shoud i just do  
  tb <- bq_project_query(projectid, sql()) ??

Comment: Using your code this is how you can construct the sql query string.

Comment: When i try to use the code below, i get the error: Erro: query is not a string (a length one character vector).

Comment: In your question you have not provided information about many variables you mention: `custo_rest_min_aux`, `custo_rest_max_aux`, `month_rest`, and so forth. Until you provide a complete question it will be difficult to help you.

Comment: Please read about [how to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and update your question accordingly. As it stands now your post is not reproducible. You will get better help if you can create a reproducible example.

Comment: My bad, they are not important because they are fixed numeric values that i also use on my query. The only problem that i'm having now is how to pass the sql() into the function bq_project_query(projectid, sql()). The goal here is to use sql() as an string to another function

Comment: Your `bq_project_query` needs to be in a reactive consumer. Most things you want to do on the server side need to be in reactive consumers. You cannot, generally, just write code how you would normally in an R script.